# Trouble using "HLOOKUP" in Microsoft Excel 2010. Sometimes formula generates an error

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I have a table setup as-

```
      A          B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J       K       L       M
 1    Row      SDR_1   SDR_2   SDR_3   SIR_1   SIR_2   SIR_3   SAR_1   SAR_2   SAR_3   NSDR_1  NSDR_2  NSDR_3
 2  Voc_Iso     0.43   -0.53    0.79    0.72   -0.04    0.89    0.01   -0.74    0.56    0.43   -0.53    0.79
 3  Voc_Itl     0.39   -0.49    0.75   -0.48   -0.87    0.06    0.84    0.38    0.94    0.39   -0.49    0.75
 4  Voc_Ovl     0.38   -0.53    0.76    0.08   -0.73    0.65    0.61   -0.35    0.85    0.38   -0.53    0.76
```

I am using "HLOOKUP" as

```
=HLOOKUP("SDR_1",B1:M4,2)
```

it gives 0.43

however if use

```
=HLOOKUP("SAR_1",B1:M4,2)
```

it gives an error and shows #N/A when I expect 0.01.

Can someone please help me debug this. I am not able to figure this out myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `*LOOKUP` functions
expect their input to be sorted.  Alphabetically, `SAR` comes before `SDR`
(but `SAR` comes *after* `SDR` in your data),
so, as soon as `HLOOKUP` sees `SD…`, it says,
"Well, if `SAR_1` were here, I would have found it already. 
So it must not be here."

To get your formula to work, override the default by saying

```
=HLOOKUP("SAR_1", B1:M4, 2, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I could not find a way to formulate a query about my problem in google. You saved the day!

Comment: Just for fun, try `=HLOOKUP("SER", B1:M4, 2)` or `=HLOOKUP("SHE", B1:M4, 2)` (without the fourth parameter = `FALSE`).  You'll get 0.79 (from `D2`) because, when `HLOOKUP` sees the `SIR_1`, it says, "Oops; I've gone too far. Let me back up one column."